# Changing keyboard button in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

Is it possible to have the right square bracket button (<kbd>]</kbd>) produce the left square bracket (<kbd>[</kbd>) when I press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> ?

Comment: The title says Ubuntu 20 the tag says 20.04 which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the basic `x-server` tool `xkbcomp`.

First get your current keyboard layout with `xkbcomp $DISPLAY ~/.config.xkb`. Then open the `.config.xkb` file with some editor, say vscode. You can see the file consists of 5 blocks(keycodes, types, compatibility, symbols, geometry):

```
xkb_keymap {
xkb_keycodes "..." {...};
xkb_types "..." {...};
xkb_compatibility "..." {...};
xkb_symbols "..." {...};
xkb_geometry "..." {...};
}
```

In the `xkb_types` block, add:

```
type "newType" {
    modifiers= Shift+Alt;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[Alt]= Level3;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Alt";
};
```

In the `xkb_symbols` block, find the following  sub-block:

```
key <AD12> {         [    bracketright,      braceright ] };
```

And change the sub-block to:

```
key <AD12> {                 type= "newType",
    symbols[Group1]= [              bracketright,      braceright, bracketleft],
    actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<AD11>, clearmods=Alt) ]
 };
```

Finally, to make it into effect, run `xkbcomp ~/.config.xkb $DISPLAY`, and see if it satisfies your requirement. If necessary, set it to automatically run at startup.

For more information on `xkbcomp`, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas how to make this work for shift + ctrl?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Isn't it obvious? Just replace `Alt` with `Control`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working in the terminal right after I execute `xkbcomp ~/.config.xkb $DISPLAY` but not in other programs. Perhaps running it at startup will achieve what I want. Will restart & check

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this only works in the terminal but not in other programs eg Firefox or Pluma. May be it has something to do with alt being ignored by other programs. I tried replacing Alt with Control in the `types` block but it didn't work even in terminal.

Comment: Btw, I don't know why Shift is being included in the modifiers - in the terminal, I only have to do alt + left bracket and it works.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Sorry for my mistake, I have updated the answer. The modifier `Shift` is to guarantee that you can input `}` with `Shift+]`. If it still does not work, no reboot is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! It works now :)

Comment: Can we be friends? You're by far the most knowledgeable linux person I know :P. My contact info is on my site in my profile.